# Checking if array is out of bounds while checking if item has been visited

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to find if the current cell has any neighbours and if they exist I want to know if I've visited them before.

```
if (!Ar[x, y + 1].HasBeenVisited && y + 1 <= (Width / TileWidth))
            return true;
```

But it seem that when I check the HasBeenVisited parameter it goes out of bounds.

```
  Ar[x, y + 1].HasBeenVisited
```

Should I be checking the if the array is out of bounds and THEN check if it has been visited in a double if(), or is there a simpler way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the bounds first. If it's false, it will quit before checking the rest, where it would throw an error, because of the Short-circuit evaluation.

Just switch them.

```
if (y + 1 <= (Width / TileWidth) && !Ar[x, y + 1].HasBeenVisited)
```

Comment: It seems I stil get an  System.IndexOutOfRangeException error when chercking the lower bound and x=0

Comment: When you say Maze[x - 1, y] != null && x - 1 >= 0 && !Maze[x - 1, y].HasBeenVisited you are using [x - 1, y] of the maze before checking if it's in bounds. The bounds check always needs to be the first.

Comment: Ahh I see my bad, I changed it to: if (y + 1 <= (Width / TileWidth) && Maze[x, y + 1] != null & !Maze[x, y + 1].HasBeenVisited) but I still get an System.IndexOutOfRangeException when y = maxindex

Comment: Then just write "y + 1 < (Width / TileWidth)" or "y <= (Width / TileWidth)"

Comment: just realised that hahaha, it seems that I did my math wrong, it works now. Thanks for the help, and sorry for the stupid questions!

Comment: No question is stupid if you already tried your best by yourself! Sometimes four eyes see more than two.